# Listing all folders in a menu system

Tags: php

I'm trying to use scandir() to list all folders in a directory into a menu structure I am making.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
$directory = "models/";
$files = scandir($directory);

echo "  <a class=\"menuitem submenuheader\" href=\"#\" >models</a>
        <div class=\"submenu\">\n
        <ul>\n";

foreach($files as $file)
{
     if(is_dir($file))
     {
        echo "<li><a href=\"$file.html\">$file</a></li>\n";
     }
}
echo "</ul>\n</div>\n";
```

I think I'm having an issue in the if(is_dir($file) line of the code.
It is listing two items in the menu (.) and (..).

Thanks for any/all help that is offered!  I very much appreciate it.

To do some testing, I replaced the foreach loop with a for loop.

```
$directory = "models/";
$folders = scandir($directory);

echo "<a class=\"menuitem submenuheader\" href=\"#\" >models</a>\n";
echo "<div class=\"submenu\">\n";
echo "<ul>\n";

for ($i=0; $i<count($folders); $i++) {
     if ($folders[$i] != '.' && $folders[$i] != '..') {
         if(is_dir($folders[$i])) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"" . $folders[$i] . ".html\">" . $folders[$i] . "</a></li>\n";
         }
     }
}
echo "</ul>\n</div>\n";
```

Still doesn't work (Won't pull a folder within the $directory)
BUT, if I change the

```
if(is_dir($folders[$i]))
```

to

```
if(!is_dir($folders[$i]))
```

it lists all the files as well as the single folder in the $directory.
Not sure why it is doing this.  Any ideas?

Comment: `.` is the current folder and `..` is the previous folder, they are technically inside the folder.

Comment: `.` and `..` are present in ALL folders.

Comment: Maybe I have the $directory listed wrong.  There is another folder in my actual target folder which is not being listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!!!

I guess is_dir() must list the FULL PATH to the folder in question, otherwise, it doesn't work.  I changed my code to this:

```
if(is_dir($directory . $folders[$i])) {
```

and it works perfect!

Thanks again for everyones help!  Brainstorming with this site gets my brain juices flowing...

Answer (score 0):

The comments are right. You can just add in your conditional to ignore those:

```
if(is_dir($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..')
{
   echo "<li><a href=\"$file.html\">$file</a></li>\n";
}
```

Unless what you're saying is these are the ONLY results and there should be more.

Also, make sure you're calling the path correctly. You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and build your correct path from there. Something like this:

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/models/";
```

Comment: Yes, there should be one more folder in there.  I'm thinking my $directory is listed wrong.  The menu is populating in domain.com/index.php, but is called from domain.com/inc/menu.inc. The actual target folder is at domain.com/models/.  Thanks again for all this help!  Love this site!!!

Comment: Nope. Still not listing the folder within the /models/ folder.

Comment: are there any options to go along with scandir()???  maybe I'm missing something...